# C++, Keep Adding Records To a File besd on User confirmation

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io

Below code is able to send a single student information to a file at once. How can it modified to send more records one after another without exiting and re-opening the program. I'm new for this. Kindly help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <dos.h>
using namespace std;
string userName;
string passWord;
string selection;
int option;

struct patientinfo {
    string PatientFname;
    string PatientLname;
    int Age;
    int ContactNo;
    string TreatmentType;
    string AppDate;
    string AppTime;
    int eReciptId;
};

int num;
patientinfo emp[50];
void makeBooking()
{

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("smt.bin", std::ofstream::in | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

int i=num;
num+=1;

cout<< endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
<< setw(30)<<"First Name       : ";
cin>>emp[i].PatientFname;
outputFile <<emp[i].PatientFname <<",";
cout<< setw(30)<<"Last Name        : ";
cin>>emp[i].PatientLname;
outputFile <<emp[i].PatientLname <<",";
cout<< setw(30)<<"Age        : ";
cin>>emp[i].Age;
outputFile <<emp[i].Age <<",";

}


int main ()
{
    makeBooking();

    return 0;   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have 50 students to whom you want to send information you should call the makeBooking function 50 times. So changing your main in

```
int main ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        makeBooking();
    }

    return 0;   

}
```

should do the trick.
However, a more elegant solution would be to send the index **i** as a parameter in your function. So the code would be:

```
patientinfo emp[50];
void makeBooking(int i)
{

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("smt.bin", std::ofstream::in | std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);

// int i=num; you don't need these anymore
// num+=1;

cout<< endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl 
<< setw(30)<<"First Name       : ";
cin>>emp[i].PatientFname;
outputFile <<emp[i].PatientFname <<",";
cout<< setw(30)<<"Last Name        : ";
cin>>emp[i].PatientLname;
outputFile <<emp[i].PatientLname <<",";
cout<< setw(30)<<"Age        : ";
cin>>emp[i].Age;
outputFile <<emp[i].Age <<",";

}


int main ()
{
    char response;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50;) {
        cout << "Do you want to add another person?";
        cin >> response;
        if (response == 'y')
             makeBooking(i++);
        else if (respinse == 'n')
             break;
        else 
             cout << "Undefined response";
    }

    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: Actually I need to add based on user confirmation. once add the first record program should ask "do you want to add another record?" If "Y" pressed it should continue to add a new record. If "n" exit the program. Apologies if I was not clear previously.

Comment: Well, then you should modify the code a little bit but the idea is the same. I will edit my post :)